# How to change Locale of .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there a way to change the locale of .Net Core 3.1? Perhaps via dotnet CLI? Right now it's using `,` for decimals instead of `.`.

I'm working on a console application using .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: are you making an asp.net core application or something else?

Comment: @DanielA.White no it's a console application.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AssertYourAssumptionsNETCoreAndSubtleLocaleIssuesWithWSLsUbuntu.aspx some thoughts

Comment: Add a new file named AssemblyInfo.cs with this line:
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]

Comment: or hack this as the first line of your Main method:

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;`

Comment: @Josh the `AssemblyInfo.cs` didn't work. However adding `System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture; System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;` to the Main method did. You should post answer :D

Answer (score 2):

at startup of your application:

```cs
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
  = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
```

or `"fr"` or `"the culture of your choice"`

or to go straight to the point (less good to my opinion):

```cs
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator="";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator="";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator=".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator=".";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in `Main` method just as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1#examples):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH", false);
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo( "ja-JP", false);
```

`CultureInfo` object is prefered way of doing that instead of `CurrentThread`. Please see Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).